# Can't power on if once after battery drains the last drop

Tags: 14.04, boot, power-management, laptop, battery

It has happened three times. 
I put my computer here and go to sleep. When I get up, the battery drains the last drop. So I connect the power cord. And restart computer, but the screen just turns full purple with nothing for few seconds and then turn full black for many hours. But it still runs, because I need long press the power button to shutdown and press again it will turn to full purple again. And I only can reinstall Ubuntu. After happen 3 times, I find the common point is Ubuntu runs until battery drains the last drop. How can I avoid this or repair Ubuntu after this happens? It will take much time to reinstall Ubuntu and many software. And my job makes me can't charge in time every time.
I use Macbook air and use refind to manage MACOS and Ubuntu16.04.4 and the kernel is 4.13.0-37

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can teach the system to warn ealier and change to the suspension mode by changing the %-values of the battery charge in the battery options. Since you didn't say which environment you use, I can't tell you how it's called on your system specificly.

Comment: I use Ubuntu16.04.4, Can you tell me how it's called on my system? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Most likely "Power management". As an alternative you can search in the "Software Center" for a program.

Comment: I'll try after reinstalling Ubuntu again, thank you very much!